# Transitive Dependencies on generated (gGRPC) code with java/maven

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

We have a `server` and `client` application which shall talk to each other, both written in java and built with maven.

They interact via a gRPC interface.

We have different dependency situations on `server` and `client`:

```
server                         client
  |                               |
  --> lib-a                       --> *.protobuf
  |   |
  |   --> *.protobuf
  --> lib-b
  |   |
  |   --> *.protobuf
  --> *.protobuf
```

The `server` includes libraries `lib-a` and `lib-b` which in turn need a *subset* of the messages that are defined in `*.protobuf`. The server also needs some the stuff from `*.protobuf` for himself.

The `client` needs raw the `*.protobuf`-files (not just generated java sources) to generate some more code from it (for use with mutiny).

We have the raw `*.protobuf` sources are in a separate repository and now we need to distribute them somehow. The other dependencies are all managed by maven (`server->lib-a, server->lib-b`)

We have some options how to provide this dependency.

1. Generate classfiles from `*.protobuf` and **distribute them as maven artifacts**
2. Include the repository that contains `*.protobuf` as a **git-submodule**

but with each variant we face some problems:

problems with 1): the `client` needs access to the raw `*.protobuf` file to generate some more stuff from it (mutiny). Is there a way to distribute the raw file via maven as well? I also heared  that it may be a bad practice to distribute generated code as maven artifacts(?)

problems with 2): we have a git-submodule in `lib-a`, that would generate all `*.class` files from `*.protobuf` and include these generated sources in it's published artifact. The same thing happens in `lib-b`. If both libraries are released independently, it may happen that they include different versions of the generated sources. This may lead to issues when the `server` includes both. In contrast to the maven-managed dependency, this is not explicit an there will be no warnings in the compile-process. Moreover, we would like to exclude `SNAPSHOT` dependencies in our releases (which we currently enforce with `maven-enforcer-plugin`). Is there some best-practice to achieve the same with git-submodules (my current best idea is to restrict allowed branch names for submodules in CI pipeline ...)

I would really appreciate some advice here :)

Currently, I am also doing my own reading for:

- distributing the raw `*.protobuf` files via maven (see: [Importing protocol buffer definitions between Maven projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165333/importing-protocol-buffer-definitions-between-maven-projects?rq=1))
- providing the client-generated code as an artifact as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maven and Gradle protobuf plugins include the `.proto` files in the same library `.jar` as the compiled generated files (`.class`). This allows depending on a single jar and it providing the assets for protoc and javac.

I suggest making Maven libraries for your .protos and the related generated code. Treat it as a normal Java library.

Comment: how would i configure the protoc in `client` to find the `.proto` files inside of the `proto-lib`?

Comment: Just add a normal Java dependency on `proto-lib`, and the Maven/Gradle plugin will search `proto-lib` for .proto files. This is how the well-known protos are handled (e.g., Any, Struct, or the primitive wrappers), as protobuf-java includes the .proto files.